# How to apply JavaScript function to multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an image gallery, so when I click each image it opens over the page with the caption underneath.

I got it working for the first image on the page, but can't figure out how to apply it to the rest of the images. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div>
    <a href="#projects">
       <img id="myImg" src="http://qlip.in/images/webbrandaxis.jpg" 
       alt="placeholder" style="width:100%; padding-bottom: 1em">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div>
    <a href="#projects">
       <img id="myImg" src="http://qlip.in/images/webbrandaxis.jpg" 
       alt="placeholder" style="width:100%; padding-bottom: 1em">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div>
    <a href="#projects">
       <img id="myImg" src="http://qlip.in/images/webbrandaxis.jpg" 
       alt="placeholder" style="width:100%; padding-bottom: 1em">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->

<div id="myModal" class="modal" class="close"onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">
 <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
 <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); // Get modal

var img = document.getElementById('myImg'); // Get img for modal
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01"); // Place image in modal
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption"); // Use alt for caption

img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;      
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

I assume it's because JavaScript only uses the first 'id' it comes across, but I can't figure out a way around that.

Thanks

Comment: use `getElementsByClassName` for image as well

Comment: Try giving unique id to each of your <img>

Comment: use `class` instead of `id` for images because same `id` will cause problem when you are dealing with `javascript/jQuery`

Comment: IDs must be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.
Create a function and call it in the `onClick` of your image element.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); // Get modal

var img = document.getElementById('myImg'); // Get img for modal
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01"); // Place image in modal
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption"); // Use alt for caption

/*img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;      
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}*/
function showImg(ele){
modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = ele.src;      
  captionText.innerHTML = ele.alt;
}
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

/*span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div>
    <a href="#projects">
       <img id="myImg" onclick="showImg(this);" src="http://qlip.in/images/webbrandaxis.jpg" 
       alt="placeholder" style="width:100%; padding-bottom: 1em">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div>
    <a href="#projects">
       <img id="myImg" onclick="showImg(this);" src="http://qlip.in/images/webbrandaxis.jpg" 
       alt="placeholder" style="width:100%; padding-bottom: 1em">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div>
    <a href="#projects">
       <img id="myImg" onclick="showImg(this);" src="http://qlip.in/images/webbrandaxis.jpg" 
       alt="placeholder" style="width:100%; padding-bottom: 1em">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->

<div id="myModal" class="modal" class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">
 <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
 <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @cbeam776 so you can give me a green tick.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Id's should be unique. So `id="myImg1"`, `id="myImg2`, etc. If you want to reuse css classes, use classes instead of ids. So change that to class, select them all with `document.getElementsByClassName`, iterate through that array and set the event listener on all of the image objects.

Answer (score 1):

In a HTML document an ID should be unique and only be used once. Use classes instead. You can use `document.getElementsByClassName(classname)` or `document.querySelectorAll(.classname)` to select all elements with a specific class. Then you will have to use a for-loop to iterate over the returned HTMLCollections.